# Extract all rar files in a folder and subfolders using 7zip

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script, 7-zip

I have the following folder structure in Windows:

```
D:\TV Shows
|
\----Show
|    |
|    \----S01
|    |     |
|    |     \----E01
|    |     |    |
|    |     |    \----E01.rar (contains E01.mkv)
|    |     \----E02
|    |     |    |
|    |     |    \----E02.rar (contains E02.mkv)
|    |     \----E03
|    |     |    |
|    |     |    \----E03.rar (contains E03.mkv)
|    |     ...
|    \----S02
|    |     |
|    |     \----E01
|    |     |    |
|    |     |    \----E01.rar (contains E01.mkv)
|    |     \----E02
|    |     |    |
|    |     |    \----E02.rar (contains E02.mkv)
|    |     \----E03
|    |     |    |
|    |     |    \----E03.rar (contains E03.mkv)
|    |     ...    
...
```

Inside "D:\TV Shows\Show" there are a few different folders. Each folder contains a few different folders.  Each of those contains a rar file.

I want to extract all of them via batch file, rename them and move them to parent folder.
Then, delete the folder containing the rar file.

The desired outcome should be the following structure

```
D:\TV Shows
|
\----Show
|    |
|    \----S01
|    |     |
|    |     \----E01.mkv
|    |     |    
|    |     \----E02.mkv
|    |     |    
|    |     \----E03.mkv
|    |     |    
|    |     ...
|    \----S02
|    |     |
|    |     \----E01.mkv
|    |     |    
|    |     \----E02.mkv
|    |     |    
|    |     \----E03.mkv
|    |     |    
|    |     ...    
...
```

I went through several similar posts but none matched my description...

This is what I have tried (it works but it's not clean code...)

```
@echo off

for /d %%P in (*) do (
    for /d %%D in ("%%P\*") do (
        echo Now visiting %%D
        @REM extracting
        for /f "delims=" %%R in ("%%D\*.rar") do (
            "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -aos -o"%%~dpR" "%%R"
        )
        @REM renaming
        for /f "delims=" %%M in ("%%D\*.mkv") do (
            ren "%%M" "%%D.mkv"
        )
        @REM moving
        for /f "delims=" %%N in ("%%D\*.mkv") do (
            move %%N %%P
        )
        @REM deleting folder
        rmdir /q /s %%D
        echo.
    )
)
```

Comment: This would likely be much easier to do in e.g. PowerShell than batch.

Comment: So you have code that works. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: As I mentioned, it's clumsy...
I want to perfect it. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, if your code works, then it's correct and fine. If you can specifically indicate a precise and clear way in which it DOES NOT work, then you have a question and we may be able to assist you finding a solution. Right now you've already got a solution, so you don't have a question, and we haven't an answer.